# Raspberry Pi Zero W serial communication

Tags: python, serial-communication, raspberry-pi-zero

I just got a RPI zero w and I want to communicate to a device through serial comm. I also have a [MAX232 board](https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/n-arxsrf/07ifr7/products/284/images/897/MAX232_Board_2__95511.1393783698.1280.1280.png?c=2) and a [RS232 TTL converter](https://ardushop.ro/846-large_default/mcu-mini-rs232-max3232-level-to-ttl-level-converter-board-serial-converter-board-module.jpg). I want to use one of these boards to be able to communicate with that device because of what I read I can't directly use the RPI's serial pins to add parity bits which I need.

I have tried many thing to get this to work, but it seems something I'm doing is wrong and can't figure it out. The code is in python and works great if I use a USB serial converter.

```
import time
import serial
import binascii
import re


ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyAMA0',
    baudrate = 19200,
    parity = serial.PARITY_MARK,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 2
    )


while True:
        print("Connected to: " + ser.name)
        counters = [0x01,0x0F]

        ser.write(counters)
        a = ser.read(30)
        state = binascii.hexlify(a)
        asd = re.sub(rb'([0-9, a-z, A-Z])(?!$)', rb'\1,', state)
        print(asd)
```

So that's the code I'm using and I don't get any data back.

[These are the connections I made](https://ibb.co/25CzCRb)

I'm a beginner to all this stuff but I hope someone could help me make this work.

Comment: Note that we have a sister site [raspberrypi.se]. In general, Stack Overflow enforces question rules around scoping, reproducibility, &c quite strictly, more so than most other sites in the Stack Exchange network do.

Comment: ...so, on SO, a question will be accepted if it's known that the problem is explicitly, exclusively caused by code. In this case, where there are potentially also hardware issues at hand, it risks being closed as "too broad". On the RPi SE site, that concern wouldn't exist.